# Is there a way to apply django filters only if the screen has a certain size?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, media-queries

I was wondering if there is a way to apply a filter of Django in a template only if the screen has a certain size. Just like a media query does with Css.

Comment: Well you can use js and Ajax to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django gets a HTTP request from your client, and there is no information about the screen size or resolution in the request.

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233648/why-dont-http-headers-include-device-resolution-pixel-density-etc